# Package Signed APK with UBER sdk 0.5.1 return lots of error message

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk, uber-api

I got an issue with UBER SDK 0.5.1.
When I use android debug key, it is fine to create APK without any error message.
But when I create signed APK, there was lots of error message show up. 
Contains "apache httpclient 4.0.1", retrofit ....

Here's the error message as below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oce0kjodvp6rjl/uberError?dl=0

I'm using android studio to develop. Can somebody help me or give me some suggestion?

Here is my build script

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile(project(':libraries:SlidingMenuLib')) {
        exclude module: 'support-v4';
    }
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}



android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            minifyEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.FunNowconfig
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
        production {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.FunNowconfig
            versionCode = 163
            versionName '1.6.3'

        }
        stagin {
            versionCode = 163
            versionName '1.6.3Stg'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        defaultConfig {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "AUTO_UPDATES", "true"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 20
            multiDexEnabled true
            buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"${loadSecret("UBER_CLIENT_ID")}\""
            //Add your client id to gradle.properties
            buildConfigField "String", "REDIRECT_URI", "\"${loadSecret("UBER_REDIRECT_URI")}\""
            //Add your redirect uri to gradle.properties
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TOKEN", "\"${loadSecret("UBER_SERVER_TOKEN")}\""
            //Add your server token to gradle.properties
            resValue "string", "googleApiKey", "\"${loadSecret("GOOGLE_API_KEY")}\""
            resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "\"${loadSecret("FACEBOOK_APP_ID")}\""
            resValue "string", "gcm_sender_id", "\"${loadSecret("GOOGLE_GCM_SENDER_ID")}\""
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Loads property from gradle.properties and ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
 * Use to look up confidential information like keys that shoudln't be stored publicly
 * @param name to lookup
 * @return the value of the property or "MISSING"
 */
def loadSecret(String name) {
    return hasProperty(name) ? getProperty(name) : "MISSING"
}
```

My top gradle as follow.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build script here for reference? It seems like Proguard might be stripping something out that's needed.

Comment: @tsmith had update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the SDK using proguard.

Add this to your Proguard config as a short term workaround while we fix the SDK.

```
-dontwarn com.google.api.**
```

Comment: may I have another question about ride request api, this question is extend #22875,We downloaded the latest SDK and we could finish SMS verification code process. However, we saw "The Ride Request Widget encountered a problem." after that step. I'm very thankful you spend your time to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please test with the latest SDKs (0.5.2) and if the issue persists, please provide logs and more details for repro.

Comment: Hi tsmith, the 0.5.2's path is not put correct jar, the gradle can't find it.

Comment: Hey, it's in Maven Central. Please check for typo's. For reference, here's the link http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.uber.sdk%7Crides-android%7C0.5.2%7Caar . If you still get an issue, posting the output would help me diagnose it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @tsmith. I'm trying to change jcenter to Maven, and I got another error message as below. "ould not find core-android.jar (com.uber.sdk:core-android:0.5.2).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/uber/sdk/core-android/0.5.2/core-android-0.5.2.jar". I edit my question to add my gradle config..

Comment: I noticed that the AAR was missing from the .5.2 release, probably a botched release. I've resynced our deploy to Maven Central and it's there now. Give it another shot.

Comment: Hi tsmith, I still got same error from 0.5.2, but when I back to 0.5.1 everything is fine..